# Especific regular expression

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that validates 3 different cases:

1. 99.99
2. F99.9
3. F/S99.9

The dot could be replaced by a comma

I have something like this `[F|F/S]?\d*[\,.]\d*` but i can't make the third case work

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `^(F(/S)?)?99\.9$`.  Next!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use optional groups, not a character class:

```
(?:F(?:/S)?)?\d*[,.]\d+
^^   ^^  ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pZlqIn/1)

If you need to match the whole string, add anchors around, `^` and `$`: `^(?:F(?:/S)?)?\d*[,.]\d+$`.

*Details*:

- `(?:F(?:/S)?)?` - an optional `F` that is optionally followed with `/S`
- `\d*` - 0+ digits (if you expect at least 1 digit, replace `*` with `+`)
- `[,.]` - a comma or dot
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.

Comment: An excerpt from the deleted Aaron's answer: *The third case doesn't work because you did not write your first regex fragment correctly : `[...]` is a character class, that will match any of the characters it contains. You've suffixed it with the `?` quantifier which says it must match 0 or 1 time, so it can't match the 3 characters `F/S`.* In short: a character class matches a single char defined inside the class, and the quantifier applied to the class defines how many such chars will be matched. You actually need a *grouping* construct rather than a char class (as I already mentioned above).

Comment: This is what i was looking for, you're a genious Wiktor! Thank you very much!